# Driver for a racing wheel

Tags: ubuntu-drivers, joystick

is there any driver or something for ACME STI Racing Wheel on Ubuntu? Cause I tried playing any racing game on Ubuntu but the game just doesn't work with the Racing Wheel.

Comment: Did you install the driver? http://www.acme.eu/en-us/support/accessories/gaming-devices/wheels/acme-sti-racing-wheel

Comment: I mean I need an Ubuntu driver, not for Windows but for Linux.

Comment: Ok use wine it should work fine